# To refresh something on my new laptop I need to do a Fn + F5, instead of just F5. How to revert this behaviour to just F5?

Tags: windows, hotkeys, hp-pavilion

I guess this must have something to do with a "new" convention my new HP Pavilion has. When I press F5 the computer interprets it as what my old Tx2000 would do with Fn + F5, and when I do a Fn + F5, it interprets it as an old F5.

I don't really like this new approach to my F keys. How to change it back?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can usually change that in the BIOS. See [here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02035108&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&jumpid=reg_R1002_USEN).

Answer (score 0):

look on your keyboard for a FN Lock.